# java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile error

Tags: string, class, exception, multipartform-data, classcastexception

I am trying to store a string which i am getting using params.get("uploadedFile") in a MultipartFile class object,something like the below code:

**MultipartFile mul = (MultipartFile)params.get("uploadedFile");**

But it is throwing me java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile error.How to resolve and proceed then ?

Comment: Do you config the form to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @Liping Huang No,i did not config any form.i simply want to assign a string which i am getting as a post parameter to a MultipartFile class object. But it is giving me exception at the time of casting.

Comment: Can i get any help here ?